# How to handle deps while using rebar to release?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm using `rebar generate` to handle release, but when I start the
application, the deps I use will not be found.`

I can start the application manually using `erl -pa ./ebin ./deps/*/ebin -s myapp`.

I'm wonder how to config `rebar.config` and `reltool.config` to handle
dependencies? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for reltool to generate a release which includes the dependencies, you will need to add them to `reltool.config`.  I have an application called `drill_instructor`, which has the following `reltool.config`.  The lines like `{app, stdlib, [{incl_cond, include}]},` tell reltool to include that application in the release.  I also added deps to `the lib_dirs` setting.

```
{sys, [
   {lib_dirs, ["../deps"]},
   {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
   {app_file, strip},
   {rel, "drill_instructor", "1",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib,
     sasl,
     crypto,
     ranch,
     jiffy,
     cowboy,
     jiffy,
     drill_instructor
    ]},
   {rel, "start_clean", "",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib
    ]},
   {boot_rel, "drill_instructor"},
   {profile, embedded},
   {incl_cond, exclude},
   {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs
   {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*", "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",
                       "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},
   {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},
   {app, sasl,   [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, crypto,   [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, stdlib, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, kernel, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, cowboy, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, ranch, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, jiffy, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, drill_armory, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, drill_instructor, [{incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, ".."}]}
  ]}.

{target_dir, "drill_instructor"}.

{overlay, [
       {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
       {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
       {copy, "files/nodetool", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/nodetool"},
       {copy, "files/drill_instructor", "bin/drill_instructor"},
       {copy, "files/drill_instructor.cmd", "bin/drill_instructor.cmd"},
       {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},
       {copy, "files/install_upgrade.escript", "bin/install_upgrade.escript"},
       {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},
       {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}
      ]}.
```

In the rebar.config, I also added rel as a `sub_dir`:

```
{sub_dirs, ["rel"]}.
```

Comment: Thanks, the key is `{lib_dirs, ["../deps"]}`